# Laravel 8: Undefined property: App\Notifications\ResetPassword::$queue

Tags: php, laravel, notifications, queue, laravel-8

I want tp apply **queue** for my Notifications, so I implemented that at my Notification which `ResetPassword`:

```
class ResetPassword extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
```

Then I ran `php artisan queue:table` and migrate it so the table `jobs` created successfully at the DB.

And also change the `QUEUE_CONNECTION` to `database` at `.env` file and re-run `php artisan serve`.

But when I test this and clicked on reset password link, a new table row must be added to `jobs` table but it does not.

And instead of that, this error returns:

> **ErrorException** Undefined property:
> App\Notifications\ResetPassword::$queue
> ...\notification\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationSender.php:195

So what is going wrong here ? How can I fix this issue ?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE #1**:

`ResetPassword.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;

class ResetPassword extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    /**
     * The password reset token.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $token;

    /**
     * The callback that should be used to build the mail message.
     *
     * @var \Closure|null
     */
    public static $toMailCallback;

    /**
     * Create a notification instance.
     *
     * @param  string  $token
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array|string
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Build the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        if (static::$toMailCallback) {
            return call_user_func(static::$toMailCallback, $notifiable, $this->token);
        }

        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('subject goes here')
            ->line('This email is sent to you')
            ->action(Lang::get('Reset Password'), url(config('app.url').route('password.reset', ['token' => $this->token, 'email' => $notifiable->getEmailForPasswordReset()], false)))
            ->line(Lang::get('Until the next 60 minutes you can use this link', ['count' => config('auth.passwords.'.config('auth.defaults.passwords').'.expire')]))
            ->line(Lang::get('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.'));
    }

    /**
     * Set a callback that should be used when building the notification mail message.
     *
     * @param  \Closure  $callback
     * @return void
     */
    public static function toMailUsing($callback)
    {
        static::$toMailCallback = $callback;
    }
}
```

Comment: @JohnLobo I just added an **UPDATE #1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look Like you have forgot to use `Queueable` `Trait` in your `notification`

```
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
class ResetPassword extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{

   use Queueable;
```

`Queueable trait` has propety `$queue`

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#queued-notifications-and-database-transactions